# React Native app won't build after update

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode8

I recently came back to an old React Native project that was originally built with React Native 0.23, I have tried to update the app to the latest version of React Native 0.43.3. I now have a problem where the iOS app will fail to build with the error

```
ld: library not found for -lRCTWebSocketDebugger
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC at some point (can't remember which version), `RCTWebSocketDebugger.xcodeproj` was renamed to `RCTWebSocket.xcodeproj` so you need to remove the dependency on the old lib through XCode and then run `react-native link` to take a dependency on the new lib.

Comment: You said so 'you need to remove the dependency on the old lib through XCode'. Can you please explain? I'm having same issue. I'm using  "react-native": "0.57.8". Please help.